# 'Proof' of backwards movement on a prolate cycloid?

Tags: calculus

I was looking at this web page: http://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/rolling.htm
and had a hard time understanding the prolate cycloid bit at the bottom. Using the example from that website, the vector function is x(t),y(t) = (r(ωt  + sin ωt), r(1 + cos ωt)). They didn't go into showing mathematically how the section below the x axis is moving backward. I need help understanding how the backwards moving section of the curve applies to a vector function.